# How to detect software keyboard was displayed on another apps on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard

I'd like to know how to detect software keyboard was displayed on another apps on iOS. Situation is below:

1. Showing alert dialog with OK button on our app.
2. If user taps OK button, 'App Store' and our app's page will be displayed.
3. User shows software keyboard on App Store.
4. User returns to our app.

I'd like to detect whether user showed software keyboard on App Store or not on sequence no 4.

Our project manager wants users to write app store's review and wants to know whether user wrote review or not.

But it's impossible to detect another app's events. So alternatively, I want to know whether user showed software keyboard on App Store or not.

If user showed software keyboard on App Store, we can judge that 'user wrote review', it's enough.

Some apps implement this function so I think there are some tips to realize it, but I wasn't able to find good informations or articles.

Does anyone know how to realize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not detect if other apps are showing virtual keyboard or not on iPhone. But you can try your luck with some thing like this.

```
    NSDictionary* infoDictionary = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
    NSString* appID = infoDictionary[@"CFBundleIdentifier"];
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=%@", appID]];
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSDictionary* lookup = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I didn't know that Apple gives us such api, thank you very much for your great information. 

And after investigating some apps, I concluded that I was misunderstanding. Those apps don't detect if virtual keyboard was shown on other apps or not. They simply measure 'elapsed time' after user pushing OK button(from 1 minute to 10 minutes, randomly).
Thank you and I'm sorry for my wrong question.

Comment: I am glad it answered your question, instead of measuring random time, you can check the review count before and after using above code. It is also not a perfect answer but it is more logical compared to others.

Comment: Thank you for your reply again and I'm sorry for my late reply! (I didn't checked Stack Overflow on Saturday and Sunday, I'm sorry) Yes I checked lookup api last week, but Apple doesn't seem to update review count in real time. So I decided to use random time logic. But your informatin is great and I will use lookup api on another occasion. Thanks!

Comment: ok, np, now it looks logical. When you write a review it will not appear on the reviews section instantaneously, it will take few hours to get updated. So technically for your original question, the answer is a BIG NO. :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply again! Yes now I understand we can't detect other application's events or keyboard status on iOS, thank you for your great answer!

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't know 'accept' function on StackOverflow! Now I checked 'accept' button but I wasn't able to vote your answer because my reputation point under 15. (It seems 15 reputation is required to vote) I'm sorry and thank you very much.

Comment: Yes I know that. But when I click triangle, message box appears and it says that 'Vote Up requires 15 reputation'. So I can't vote your answer. I will vote your answer after my reputation over 15 in the future! Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I also have the same issue, I have less reputation and want to increasing. :)

Comment: Year I think I should answer some questions and get more reputation! Thanks :)